# Can I assign a function as a property in this.state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-redux, this

Im trying to render the last value of a string in a div, using this.handleFormula function. Im assigning this function to formula in this.state and linking this.state.formula to a div. Im trying to console.log the return value but still nothing is rendering, do you what could be the issue?

here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/tonytony92/pen/bGdmbzx?editors=1111

```
    this.state={
      display:"0",
      formula:this.handleFormula,
      buttonState:[{key: 'AC',
        col:'red',
        key1:"AC"
        },///and a bunch of other objects in array/// ]  }

handleFormula(){
    let str=this.state.display
    console.log(str)
    let newArr=str.match(/["/"+"x"-]/gi)
    let newStr=""
    if (Boolean(newArr)==false){//If no special characters are found in string ,return current display//
      console.log(str)
      return str
    }
    else{
       for(let i=newArr.length-1;i>-1;i--){// if last value is a number concatenate it to a variable///
        if(parseFloat(newArr[i])!==NaN){
             newStr+=newArr[i]
           } 
         else if(i===newArr.length-1&& parseFloat(newArr[i])===NaN){ // if last value is a specialChar return it///
           return newArr[i]
         }
         else{  /// return numbers concatenated in variable///
           return newStr
         }

       }

    }

  }
```

Comment: Why? It's already a class function, why are you putting it in state?

Comment: Can you also provide a list of steps to repro your issue? Your code is a bit of a mess and I see quite a few react anti-patterns that make following what is going on a bit more difficult.

Comment: @Drew Reese .Ok , thanks for your response.This is the app that Im currently using as an example https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/wgGVVX . Everytime a calculation is made , the whole calculation is rendered in an upper display, while only the last value of the string is rendered in the bottom display div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't render function, same as it doesn't render booleans.

If you want to render function declaration (which doesn't makes much sense), instead of `{this.state.formula}` use `{this.state.formula.toString()}` in your div.

But since you are expecting to render return value of your `handleFormula` it woud be better if `handleFormula` would be setting some piece of state and than you can render just that piece of state.

Why is that better? Because setting new state will cause re-render and you will always see new state in UI. Rendering return value of `this.state.formula` will be always the same and you might see that as a bug.

N.B. It is unusual to attach function to the state, but it should not cause problem of any kind. I've been seeing that peple do that in Context provider due performance reasons: `value={this.state}` where they attach methods to the state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean up. You cant use function in the state. The state is only for data that can change over of period of time.

You can look at my implementation and get some idea.
https://codesandbox.io/s/calculatorreact-gi30v

Like buttonState, should be not part of state. It can move to class property

```
this.buttonState = [
      { key: "AC", col: "red", key1: "AC" },
      { key: "/", col: "gray", key1: "divide", keypress: "o", divide: "/" },
      { key: "x", col: "gray", key1: "multiply", keypress: "j" },
      // rest
      { key: "=", col: "gray", key1: "equals" },
      { key: ".", col: "gray", key1: "point", keypress: "n" },
      { key: "CC", col: "red", key1: "delete" }
    ];
```

Add a new state prop for string you want to dispay in view

```
this.state = {
      display: "0",
      formula: this.handleFormula,
      str: ""
    };
```

Update string when u want to display the latest value after formula executed .

```
handleFormula() {
    let str = this.state.display;
    let newArr = str.match(/["/"+"x"-]/gi);
    let newStr = "";
    if (newArr) {
      return str;
    } else {
      for (let i = newArr.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        if (parseFloat(newArr[i]) !== NaN) {
          newStr += newArr[i];
        } else if (i === newArr.length - 1 && parseFloat(newArr[i]) === NaN) {
          return newArr[i];
        } else {
          return this.setState({str: newStr});
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

You can look at my implementation and get some idea.
https://codesandbox.io/s/calculatorreact-gi30v

Comment: Thankyou! Instead of calling this.state.formula in the div I just called the method itself in divs inner text.